# Netbeans code completion too agressive?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, code-completion

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1  I am a bit new to Java, and using Java IDE for the first time.
I have enabled code completion in Netbeans.

The problem I am facing is that the netbeans code completion feature is too aggressive, for example if I type "p" and it shows "public", "private" and "protected" as options then instead of filtering the list as I type more letters, it instead types the first word in the list.

Instead, I want it like intellisense of visual studio, which filters the list of possible words as you type.

Comment: Any reason to stay with 7.0.1 when 8.0 is last stable one ? Because I canot reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: try using intellij idea...much more helpful in code completion.